# Codeigniter URL routing issues in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

Before you mark it as duplicate FIY I have tried all solutions I could find on SO.

The url is [www.deltadigital.ca](http://www.deltadigital.ca)

config file (if I use $config['base_url']   = 'http://www.deltadigital.ca' - it doesnt work at all)

```
//$config['base_url']   = 'http://www.deltadigital.ca';
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|woff|eot|img|css|js|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It's giving me my webhost's 404 error. I tried other solutions on SO and it's either giving me 500 server error or codeidniter's 404 error

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "tlc/view";
$route['/([a-z]+)'] = "tlc/view/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

And this is my controller

```
class Tlc extends CI_Controller
    public function view($page='index')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/tlc/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        } 
         else
         {
            $this->load->view('tlc/templates/header.php');
            $this->load->view('tlc/'.$page);   
            $this->load->view('tlc/templates/footer.php');   
        }
```

So basically Im trying to make menu links work. They only work with full url i.e. deltadigital.ca/index.php/tlc/view/about-us

It's CI 2.2.2, host is 1and1, my view files are in views/tlc folder

update: removed the leading slash: 
`$route['([a-z]+)'] = "tlc/view/$1";`

Comment: Surely the base URL should be blank? CI obtains that for you...

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. I tried other rewrite rules after setting to blank. So is this a problem with the server settings?

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps remove the leading slash from your second route? Documentation says it is important to leave those out. Also, your base URL should be defined *with* the trailing slash: `$config['base_url'] = "http://www.deltadigital.ca/"`.

Comment: Yes, I added the trailing slash ...www.deltadigital.ca/   Ive tried different rules I found online and the one Im using now is RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] - so it has no leading slash anyway, still doesn't work.

Comment: If I remove the leading slash its giving me 500 server error which indicates there is an error in .htaccess, with the leading slash it's just giving me my webhosts 404. Thank you anyway

Comment: I'm talking about the leading slash from your route configuration, not your `.htaccess` file. `$route['/([a-z]+)']` - Remove that leading slash.

Comment: Oh yea, I removed that too, and tried `$route['(:any)'] = 'tlc/view/$1';` and also tried removing it altogether, no luck.

Comment: What is you default controller name ??

Comment: I checkd your site its working perfectly. You are gng gng out with routings. Othervice no error at all

Comment: Sooo all menu links work? That's weird

Comment: @Abdulla - Unfortunately, that is not the case here. I'm getting blank pages at the moment...

Comment: @VeganSv - Perhaps change `file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/tlc/` to `file_exists(APPPATH.'views/tlc/` (without the slash before `views`)...

Comment: @Mike, thank you, tried that, no luck.

Comment: Yaa. When you type index.php after your url ur page is working well

Comment: Now `www.deltadigital.ca/index` works previously this wouldn't work.

Comment: `APPPATH.'views/tlc/` is behaving the same way as `APPPATH.'/views/tlc/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, as stated before I am not a CodeIgniter guru. What I do know is that the following works for me:

**Config:**

```php
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.deltadigital.ca/";
# or use $config['base_url'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Routes:**

```php
$route['default_controller'] = "tlc/view";
$route['(:any)'] = "tlc/view/$1";
$route['404_override'] = "";
```

**Controller:**

```php
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tlc extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page='index')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/tlc/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }
         else
         {
            $this->load->view('tlc/templates/header.php');
            $this->load->view('tlc/'.$page);
            $this->load->view('tlc/templates/footer.php');
        }
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/tlc.php */
```

**.htaccess:**

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove /index/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Remove trailing slashes (prevents duplicate SEO issues)
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # If not a file or directory, route everything to CI
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] # This is an alternative

</IfModule>
```

(Upon writing my answer, I see that you do not currently have the last rule, as shown.)

Comment: thank you, still the same thing, now instead of 404 its giving me 500. Im glad it works for some people. I'll keep trying

Comment: (Did you perhaps see my update? Are you 100% sure that you're using exactly what I have in my answer?)

Comment: And if you're getting a 500, what's in your Apache error logs?

Comment: I did see the update. It's a character for character copy. I did copy and paste. Thanks for your time man

Comment: I don't think I can see error logs, all I can see from 1and1 control panel is access and mail logs.

Comment: It must be a 1and1 thing then (perhaps you can ask them what the logs say?). Anyways, this works for me on three different installations (local, shared, and VPS). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again, it was a 1and1 thing indeed. It works just fine on another host. I can't believe I wasted so much time.